# How can I parse returned ODATA into an array?

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

When I issue:

```
$uri = "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/jane.doe@blah.com/contacts?`$filter=emailAddresses/any(a:a/address eq 'fred.bloggs@blah.com')"

$method = "GET"

$query = Invoke-WebRequest -Method $method -Uri $uri -Headers @{Authorization = "Bearer $token"} -ErrorAction Stop
```

$querystring = $query.Content | out-string | out-host

I get back the following 3 records:

```
{"@odata.context":"https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/$metadata#users('jane.doe%40blah.com')/contacts","value":[{"@odata.etag":"W/\"EQAAABYAAADSyGTyvqlwS5n00f5wZ/+rAAApDC6/\"",
"id":"AAMkADViZDA1ZTI5LTg0NWEtNGJhYy05YzA3LWI3MjUxNzA1MGUyOABGAAAAAADU7_adBLD4RZAfnn8KRZ6vBwDSyGTyvqlwS5n00f5wZ-_rAAAAAAEOAADSyGTyvqlwS5n00f5wZ-_rAAApEyC7AAA=","createdDateTime":"2019-09-09T1
3:39:27Z","lastModifiedDateTime":"2019-09-09T13:39:28Z","changeKey":"EQAAABYAAADSyGTyvqlwS5n00f5wZ/+rAAApDC6/","categories":[],"parentFolderId":"AQMkADViZDA1ZTI5LTg0NWEtNGJhYy05YzA3LWI3MjUxNz
A1MGUyOAAuAAAD1O-mnQSw_EWQH55-CkWerwEA0shk8r6pcEuZ9NH_cGf-qwAAAgEOAAAA","birthday":null,"fileAs":"","displayName":"Fred Bloggs","givenName":"Fred","initials":null,"middleName":null,"nickName"
:null,"surname":"Bloggs","title":null,"yomiGivenName":null,"yomiSurname":null,"yomiCompanyName":null,"generation":null,"imAddresses":[],"jobTitle":null,"companyName":null,"department":null,"o
fficeLocation":null,"profession":null,"businessHomePage":null,"assistantName":null,"manager":null,"homePhones":[],"mobilePhone":null,"businessPhones":["+1 732 555 0103"],"spouseName":null,"pe
rsonalNotes":"Note 3","children":[],"emailAddresses":[{"name":"Fred Bloggs","address":"fred.bloggs@blah.com"}],"homeAddress":{},"businessAddress":{},"otherAddress":{}},{"@odata.etag":"W/\"EQA
AABYAAADSyGTyvqlwS5n00f5wZ/+rAAApDC62\"","id":"AAMkADViZDA1ZTI5LTg0NWEtNGJhYy05YzA3LWI3MjUxNzA1MGUyOABGAAAAAADU7_adBLD4RZAfnn8KRZ6vBwDSyGTyvqlwS5n00f5wZ-_rAAAAAAEOAADSyGTyvqlwS5n00f5wZ-_rAAAp
EyC6AAA=","createdDateTime":"2019-09-09T13:39:15Z","lastModifiedDateTime":"2019-09-09T13:39:15Z","changeKey":"EQAAABYAAADSyGTyvqlwS5n00f5wZ/+rAAApDC62","categories":[],"parentFolderId":"AQMkA
DViZDA1ZTI5LTg0NWEtNGJhYy05YzA3LWI3MjUxNzA1MGUyOAAuAAAD1O-mnQSw_EWQH55-CkWerwEA0shk8r6pcEuZ9NH_cGf-qwAAAgEOAAAA","birthday":null,"fileAs":"","displayName":"Fred Bloggs","givenName":"Fred","in
itials":null,"middleName":null,"nickName":null,"surname":"Bloggs","title":null,"yomiGivenName":null,"yomiSurname":null,"yomiCompanyName":null,"generation":null,"imAddresses":[],"jobTitle":nul
l,"companyName":null,"department":null,"officeLocation":null,"profession":null,"businessHomePage":null,"assistantName":null,"manager":null,"homePhones":[],"mobilePhone":null,"businessPhones":
["+1 732 555 0102"],"spouseName":null,"personalNotes":"Note 2","children":[],"emailAddresses":[{"name":"Fred Bloggs","address":"fred.bloggs@blah.com"}],"homeAddress":{},"businessAddress":{},"
otherAddress":{}},{"@odata.etag":"W/\"EQAAABYAAADSyGTyvqlwS5n00f5wZ/+rAAApDC6r\"","id":"AAMkADViZDA1ZTI5LTg0NWEtNGJhYy05YzA3LWI3MjUxNzA1MGUyOABGAAAAAADU7_adBLD4RZAfnn8KRZ6vBwDSyGTyvqlwS5n00f5
wZ-_rAAAAAAEOAADSyGTyvqlwS5n00f5wZ-_rAAApEyC5AAA=","createdDateTime":"2019-09-09T13:38:47Z","lastModifiedDateTime":"2019-09-09T13:38:48Z","changeKey":"EQAAABYAAADSyGTyvqlwS5n00f5wZ/+rAAApDC6r
","categories":[],"parentFolderId":"AQMkADViZDA1ZTI5LTg0NWEtNGJhYy05YzA3LWI3MjUxNzA1MGUyOAAuAAAD1O-mnQSw_EWQH55-CkWerwEA0shk8r6pcEuZ9NH_cGf-qwAAAgEOAAAA","birthday":null,"fileAs":"","displayN
ame":"Fred Bloggs","givenName":"Fred","initials":null,"middleName":null,"nickName":null,"surname":"Bloggs","title":null,"yomiGivenName":null,"yomiSurname":null,"yomiCompanyName":null,"generat
ion":null,"imAddresses":[],"jobTitle":null,"companyName":null,"department":null,"officeLocation":null,"profession":null,"businessHomePage":null,"assistantName":null,"manager":null,"homePhones
":[],"mobilePhone":null,"businessPhones":["+1 732 555 0101"],"spouseName":null,"personalNotes":"Note 1","children":[],"emailAddresses":[{"name":"Fred Bloggs","address":"fred.bloggs@blah.com"}
],"homeAddress":{},"businessAddress":{},"otherAddress":{}}]}
```

Is there a preferred way to parse this into an array with a row for each record?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Using PowerShell, you can convert the response to an object using the [ConvertFrom-Json cmdlet](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/convertfrom-json?view=powershell-6)

Comment: Yes, I've been trying to get that working without much success.

Answer (score 0):

One option would be to utilize [`ConvertFrom-Json`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/convertfrom-json?view=powershell-6) which converts JSON string to a custom object, for example:

```
$uri = "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/"
$resp = Invoke-WebRequest -Method "GET" -Uri $uri -Headers @{Authorization = "Bearer $token"} 
$data = $resp.Content | ConvertFrom-Json
$data.value | ForEach-Object { #enumerate collection
    Write-Host $_.userPrincipalName
}
```

Another option is utilize [`Invoke-RestMethod`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/invoke-restmethod?view=powershell-6) instead of `Invoke-WebRequest` which *auto* converts JSON string to a custom object:

```
$uri = "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/"
$data = Invoke-RestMethod -Headers @{Authorization = "Bearer $token"} -Method GET -Uri $uri
$data.value | ForEach-Object {  #enumerate collection
    Write-Host $_.userPrincipalName
}
```